# Facebook App Invite "FBSDKAppInviteContent" not recognized

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am currently trying to implement Facebook's new "App Invites for iOS". I'm using Objective C and I have added the following frameworks:

- Bolts.framework
- FBSDKCoreKit.framework
- FacebookSDK.framework

I have also imported `<FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>` and `<FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>`. It's like the code isn't recognized, why? I get the following errors:

[image]

What do I need to do so that I can use FBSDKAppInviteContent. Also, is there a special URL or PHP/JS equivalent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you also need to import FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h
Don't forget to link FBSDKShareKit.framework to your library.

Comment: #import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>

Comment: @ShaifulIslam This does fix the problem for me. I got exact same error as in the screen shot. FBSDKAppInviteContent and FBSDKAppInviteDialog are under FBSDKShareKit framework.
Btw: I'm new to Stackoverflow. Sorry if I did something wrong here, and thanks for your advice.

Comment: Don't worry about that guy, some people are sticks in the mud. You're 100% correct, thank you @DaronTancharoen.